# Body vertical scroll adapt?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I just noticed that when a pop up window appears on facebook the default page scroll changes, and only the pop up's background becomes scrollable, while the page behind it stays the same. I tried to understand how it works but with no luck. I also have absolutely no idea how to google this, so I really hope you can help me out.

P.S.: I know this may not be considered a "real" question, but I'm completely clueless on how to address this in other terms. I apologize!

Comment: It's called a `modal window/dialog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent scrolling by mouse wheel through the [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/wheel) event:

```
window.onwheel = function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); };
```

(Note that `wheel` is available on elements as well as the `window` object, and it might be better to attach the event listener to the `body`, for example.)

To hide scroll-bars, you can set the style of the appropriate element to [`overflow:hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

To prevent touch scrolling, you can try calling `preventDefault()` on the [`touch*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events) events.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent scrolling, set `overflow: hidden` in CSS.  To enable scrolling, set `overflow: auto`.  So, when the pop up window appears, set:

```css
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#myPopup
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/yM7zb](http://jsfiddle.net/yM7zb/)

Comment: Both answers were very helpful, I only accepted Jeremy's answer due to the fact that he has much less reputation points than you. I hope that it's alright with you. Thanks!

Comment: No offense taken. :) However, be aware that Jeremy's answer only covers one way to scroll - the scroll wheel.  You can also scroll with the arrow keys, the spacebar, dragging the scroll bar, clicking the arrows on the scroll bar, etc.  A better approach would be to handle the document's `scroll` event and call `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @gilly3 actually I looked into handling `scroll` and found that `preventDefault()` didn't have an effect, at least in Firefox. From your demo though it looks like `overflow:hidden` and a full-page overlay provides exactly the behaviour @account50 wants.

Comment: @Jeremy - Yes, good call. The `scroll` event is not cancelable [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/scroll).  In that case, I don't believe you can prevent scrolling by handling events when dragging the scrollbar.